# Magento Checkout Page change

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I want to change the accordian layout of default Checkout in magento.My requirement is that "each step to be displayed in different tabs" and on clicking NEXT button checkout will switch to next tab.
I have searched the extensions but found only "One step checkout" extension which is not my requirement.

Comment: I think what you need is here : http://www.h-o.nl/blog/improved_magento_one_page_checkout_design_css_only/

Comment: Ok thanks.I am checking this.But do it needs to install One page checkout extension first?

Comment: Yes, You need to have one page checkout. this is only css which change layout of one page checkout from accordion to tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for [One Page Checkout extension](http://magento.ocodewire.com/extensions/one-page-checkout.html), which is a brief version of one step checkout extension. It is very easy to use, install and configure.